# Redirect virtual sink audio to hedphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-recording

I created null sink via this command

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=vspeaker sink_properties=device.description=virtual_speaker
```

when I open for example discord, I am able to select as an output device for discord **vitual_speaker** but I am not able to somehow redirect it to my actual headphones which are not a virtual sink.

OBS Studio provides the feature to monitor virtual sink and redirect its output to my headphones but It has a few seconds latency which is not suitable for what I need it for.

I tried to do something like this

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=vspeaker sink_properties=device.description=virtual_speaker
```

but then I cannot see any new output device in applications nor hear something from virtual sink. It just selected my headphones. I tried to run it with `$ PULSE_SINK=virtual_sink APP_NAME` but without any effect.

Is there a way to monitor or redirect virtual sink audio to actual headphones without big latency? (Something like Voicemeeter for Windows)

Comment: This link MIGHT help. https://www.onetransistor.eu/2017/10/virtual-audio-cable-in-linux-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

You are very close you need to run two commands:

1. Create your null-sink.

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Redirected_Audio sink_properties=device.description=Redirected_Audio
```

2. Redirect your new null-sink "Redirected_Audio" into your headphones.

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=Redirected_Audio.monitor sink=name_of_headphones
```

Notice that there is `.monitor` after the name of my null sink `Redirected_Audio`, this is necessary. If you change the name of your sink be sure to include `.monitor` in this command.

But what is the name of your headphones?

Run `pactl list sinks` and find the one that is your speakers, the attribute is just called `Name` it can be quite long but depends entirely on the model, for example my headphones appear as:

```
Sink #1
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo
    Description: PCM2902 Audio Codec Analogue Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 23
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 11796 /  18% / -44.68 dB,   front-right: 11796 /  18% / -44.68 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 22938 usec, configured 26000 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Audio CODEC"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Burr-Brown from TI USB Audio CODEC at usb-0000:2a:00.1-5, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:2a:00.1-usb-0:5:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:20:00.0/0000:21:08.0/0000:2a:00.1/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "08bb"
        device.vendor.name = "Texas Instruments"
        device.product.id = "2902"
        device.product.name = "PCM2902 Audio Codec"
        device.serial = "Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analogue Stereo"
        device.description = "PCM2902 Audio Codec Analogue Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    Ports:
        analog-output: Analogue Output (priority: 9900)
    Active Port: analog-output
    Formats:
        pcm
```

The name is `alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo`